# Extracting the right elements by text and span / Beautiful Soup / Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape following data:

Cuisine: 4.5
Service: 4.0
Quality: 4.5

But im having issues to scrape the right data. I tried following two Codes:

```
for bewertungen in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'histogramCommon bubbleHistogram wrap'}):

        if bewertungen.find(text='Cuisine'):
            cuisine = bewertungen.find(text='Cuisine')
            cuisine = cuisine.next_element
            print("test " + str(cuisine))

        if bewertungen.find_all(text='Service'):
            for s_bewertung in bewertungen.find_all('span', {'class':'ui_bubble_rating'}):
            s_speicher = s_bewertung['alt']
```

In the first if i get no result. In the second If i get the right elements but i get all 3 results but i can not define which ones belongs to which text (Cuisine, Service, Quality)

Can someone give me an advice how to get the right data? 
I put at the bottom the html code.

```
<div class="histogramCommon bubbleHistogram wrap">
   <div class="colTitle">\nGesamtwertung\n</div>
   <ul class="barChart">
      <li>
         <div class="ratingRow wrap">
            <div class="label part ">
               <span class="text">Cuisine</span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap row part ">
               <span alt="4.5 of five" class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="ratingRow wrap">
        <div class="label part ">
           <span class="text">Service</span>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap row part ">
           <span alt="4.0 of five" class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="ratingRow wrap">
            <div class="label part ">
               <span class="text">Quality</span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap row part "><span alt="4.5 of five" class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span></div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try the code? What's your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. According to the snippet you have pasted above, the following code should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".ratingRow"):
    category = item.select_one(".text").text
    rating = item.select_one(".row span")['alt'].split(" ")[0]
    print("{} : {}".format(category,rating))
```

Another way would be:

```
for item in soup.select(".ratingRow"):
    category = item.select_one(".text").text
    rating = item.select_one(".text").find_parent().find_next_sibling().select_one("span")['alt'].split(" ")[0]
    print("{} : {}".format(category,rating))
```

Output:

```
Cuisine : 4.5
Service : 4.0
Quality : 4.5
```